# Jupyter - notebook ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, object-detection

I have a problem since 2 days now, i'm facing this problem in the title whene trying to train and export my tfrecords. Running Anaconda3 with python 3.9 via Jupiter-Notebook.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8cZy.png)

Answer (score 0):

In `generate_tfrecord.py`, add these lines at the beginning:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('path/to/models/research') # where models/research/object_detection is
```

Comment: Now im facing this.. module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'. I tried the IO solution but nothing

Comment: I can't promise that my solution will solve this and all other subsequent problems